Determining embedded Parameterization in 3D of a 2D manifold when only the metric is given, by exploiting symmetries
I have the second fundamental form
$$E(h,\gamma) = \frac{1}{16} \frac{h \gamma^2}{ (h^2-1) (h^2+\gamma^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, $$
$$F(h,\gamma)= -\frac{1}{16}\frac{  \gamma}{ (h^2+\gamma^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, \ \ \& \ \ $$
$$G(h,\gamma) = \frac{1}{16} \frac{2 h^3 - 2 h^2 \sqrt{-1 + h^2 + \gamma^2} - 2 (-1 + \gamma^2) \sqrt{-1 + h^2 + \gamma^2} + h (-2 + \gamma^2 + \gamma^4)}{(-1 + \gamma^2)^2 (-1 + h^2 + \gamma^2)^{3/2}}$$
Which comes from a context in Physics, with no other information about the embedding of the surface whatsoever. The parameters on the surface are as $\{1<h<\infty , -\infty < \gamma < \infty \}$, and the gaussian curvature comes out
$$K = 8 \ ( \ 1 +\frac{ h}{\sqrt{-1+h^2+\gamma^2}}) $$ which is strictly positive throughout the range of parameters.
Now I can assume the parameterization to be something spherical but determining the parameterization in standard way involves solving coupled PDEs with no information of boundary conditions, as only the metric is provided in the context Expression 31 from Classifying and measuring geometry of a quantum ground state manifold.
I am almost convinced due to some physics reasons that there should be coordinates where they may appear manageable to determine the its parameterization.
How do I proceed here? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Did you try to change the variables to $x=1/h$ and $y=\gamma/h$? Then $K$ becomes a rotationally-invariant function since it depends only on $x^2+y^2$. Once you have rotational invariance of curvature, maybe the metric is also rotationally invariant (but it is not guaranteed, you have to get lucky).

thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't help.
